# Apollo Client response not in JSON format for GitHub GraphQL APIs

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I am experimenting with GraphQL on Android using apollo-client and am using GitHub's GraphQL API. I am hitting an API to give me a list of repos owned by a user. Everything works fine but the response that I get is not in JSON format but in String format.

The response looks like this:

```
Data{user=User{__typename=User, 
repositories=Repositories{__typename=RepositoryConnection, nodes= 
[Node{__typename=Repository, name=testrepository}]}}
```

when I try hitting the url through Insomnia (GraphQL rest client) I get the response in JSON format but in my app I get the response in above format. I tried passing     content-type : "application/json; charset=utf-8" in header but no success.

Here is how I am fetching the response:

```
public void fetchRepoList(String userName, String authHeader, final ResponseCallback responseCallback) {
    GraphQL.getInstance().getApolloClient(authHeader)
            .query(githubRepoList.repoListAPI.FindQuery.builder().repoOwner(userName).build())
            .enqueue(new ApolloCall.Callback<githubRepoList.repoListAPI.FindQuery.Data>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<githubRepoList.repoListAPI.FindQuery.Data> response) {
                  Log.d(TAG, "response" + response)
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@Nonnull final ApolloException exception) {

                }
            });
}
```

I want to put the response in a List of Model class and for that I need the response in JSON format. Searched for this issue but didn't got any proper solution.

I am using apollo client 0.3.2

**[Edit:1]**

I tried making the call to the GitHub GraphQL API with Okhttp and this time I got this response:

```
{"data":{"__schema":{"queryType":{"name":"Query"},"mutationType":{"name":"Mutation"},"subscriptionType":null,"types":[{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"Boolean","description":"Represents `true` or `false` values.","fields":null,"inputFields":null,"interfaces":null,"enumValues":null,"possibleTypes":null},{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"String","description":"Represents textual data as UTF-8 character sequences. This type is most often used by GraphQL to represent free-form human-readable text.","fields":null,"inputFields":null,"interfaces":null,"enumValues":null,"possibleTypes":null},{"kind":"OBJECT","name":"Query","description":"The query root of GitHub's GraphQL interface.","fields":[{"name":"codeOfConduct","description":"Look up a code of conduct by its key","args":[{"name":"key","description":"The code of conduct's key","type":{"kind":"NON_NULL","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"String","ofType":null}},"defaultValue":null}],"type":{"kind":"OBJECT","name":"CodeOfConduct","ofType":null},"isDeprecated":false,"deprecationReason":null},{"name":"codesOfConduct","description":"Look up a code of conduct by its key","args":[],"type":{"kind":"LIST","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"OBJECT","name":"CodeOfConduct","ofType":null}},"isDeprecated":false,"deprecationReason":null},{"name":"license","description":"Look up an open source license by its key","args":[{"name":"key","description":"The license's downcased SPDX ID","type":{"kind":"NON_NULL","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"String","ofType":null}},"defaultValue":null}],"type":{"kind":"OBJECT","name":"License","ofType":null},"isDeprecated":false,"deprecationReason":null},{"name":"licenses","description":"Return a list of known open source licenses","args":[],"type":{"kind":"NON_NULL","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"LIST","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"OBJECT","name":"License","ofType":null}}},"isDeprecated":false,"deprecationReason":null},{"name":"marketplaceCategories","description":"Get alphabetically sorted list of Marketplace categories","args":[{"name":"includeCategories","description":"Return only the specified categories.","type":{"kind":"LIST","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"NON_NULL","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"String","ofType":null}}},"defaultValue":null},{"name":"excludeEmpty","description":"Exclude categories with no listings.","type":{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"Boolean","ofType":null},"defaultValue":null},{"name":"excludeSubcategories","description":"Returns top level categories only, excluding any subcategories.","type":{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"Boolean","ofType":null},"defaultValue":null}],"type":{"kind":"NON_NULL","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"LIST","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"NON_NULL","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"OBJECT","name":"MarketplaceCategory","ofType":null}}}},"isDeprecated":false,"deprecationReason":null},{"name":"marketplaceCategory","description":"Look up a Marketplace category by its slug.","args":[{"name":"slug","description":"The URL slug of the category.","type":{"kind":"NON_NULL","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"String","ofType":null}},"defaultValue":null},{"name":"useTopicAliases","description":"Also check topic aliases for the category slug","type":{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"Boolean","ofType":null},"defaultValue":null}],"type":{"kind":"OBJECT","name":"MarketplaceCategory","ofType":null},"isDeprecated":false,"deprecationReason":null},{"name":"marketplaceListing","description":"Look up a single Marketplace listing","args":[{"name":"slug","description":"Select the listing that matches this slug. It's the short name of the listing used in its URL.","type":{"kind":"NON_NULL","name":null,"ofType":{"kind":"SCALAR","name":"String","ofType":null}},"defaultValue":null}],"type":{"kind":"OBJECT","name":"MarketplaceListing","ofType":null},"isDeprecated":false,"deprecationReason":null},{"name":"marketplaceListings","description":"Look up Marketplace listings","args":[{"name":"after","description":"Returns the elements in the list that come after the specified cursor.","type"
```

This response doesn't even have required data about the repositories. It is not even related to the list of repositories.

Therefore, I went back to the old method and made the call using apollo. Now, since apollo creates these model classes from standard GraphQL queries, how do I create a list of this model class.

I went through the apollo sample-app on github and came across this piece of code:

```
List<FeedEntry> feedResponseToEntriesWithRepositories(Response<FeedQuery.Data> response) {
List<FeedEntry> feedEntriesWithRepos = new ArrayList<>();
final FeedQuery.Data responseData = response.data();
if (responseData == null) {
  return Collections.emptyList();
}
final List<FeedEntry> feedEntries = responseData.feedEntries();
if (feedEntries == null) {
  return Collections.emptyList();
}
for (FeedEntry entry : feedEntries) {
  if (entry.repository() != null) {
    feedEntriesWithRepos.add(entry);
  }
}
return feedEntriesWithRepos;
}
```

Here the feedEntries() method returns the list of feeds, this method is in the auto-generated model class file in the apollo directory. I went and checked my model file and there were no methods which returns a list of repos (as in my case). The file is too large to post here but if community want's to have a look at it I can post it here.

By the way, I tried something like this with my code:

```
List<githubRepoList.repoListAPI.FindQuery.Node> repoList = new ArrayList<>();
final githubRepoList.repoListAPI.FindQuery.Data repoListData = response.data();
final List<githubRepoList.repoListAPI.FindQuery.Node> finalRepoList = repoListData.(which method to call from the auto-generated class file?)
```

Here, Node is a class in my auto-generated model file in the apollo directory and this class should have a method which returns a list of repo model class.

I know I am doing something wrong here. I think there is some other way to create of list of these model classes.

Comment: "The response looks like this" -- please provide a [mcve] showing how you are getting that output. This looks like it is a `toString()` implementation of a `Data` class, which might be perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have edited my question

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I am using toString() but the response is not in JSON format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the response is not in JSON format

The response *was* in JSON format. It is now in the form of a `githubRepoList.repoListAPI.FindQuery.Data` object. That class was code-generated for you based on your GraphQL document. Quoting [the Apollo-Android documentation](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android), with emphasis added:

> Apollo-Android is a GraphQL compliant client **that generates Java models from standard GraphQL queries**

In particular, Apollo-Android generates `toString()` implementations on those Java model classes. In your case:

- `Data` holds a `User` in a `user` field
- `User` holds a `RepositoriesConnection`, renamed to `Repositories`, in a `repositories` field
- The `repositories` collection holds a single `Repository`

The reason for using Apollo-Android is so that you do not have to deal with the JSON yourself. If, instead, you want to parse JSON yourself, get rid of Apollo-Android and just use OkHttp to make the Web service calls.

Comment: I tried making call with just okhttp but I didn't got the proper response

Comment: @localhost: So... just use the code that you have, and get your data out of the `Data` object. **It is already parsed for you**.

Comment: let me try that. I will post whatever I find

Comment: It was a silly mistake. The repo list was under user().repositories().node()